# idea sbt project when I run test case it does not compile

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, sbt

I use JUnit for the test,when I change some codes, I must make project manually, it can't auto compile like maven. If I doesn't make project it is the last time code.
Can anybody tell me why? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I need change the before launch 'make' to 'sbt action',then I run or debug project it can auto compile in SBT project.